# linux or windows terminal over the web

Tags: linux, node.js, web, terminal, terminal-emulator

I'm planing to make a web app which will allow you to have a Linux Terminal on a web page so that you can execute any command an get the response as if you were in front of your linux terminal.
I planed to use NodeJS as it is server side JavaScript, asynchronous and fast.

Also I saw [this](http://runnable.com/me/U-aWvTUyxppA4Hrl)  wich does exactly what i'm trying to do,  I peeked in the source code, but didn't found something useful, I also analysed it with google chrome developer tools on the network tab, but there is absolutely nothing even while executing some commands and getting responses. How is this possible ? what technology do you think they used ?

So I wanted to get your advice, your experience in order to start it the right way.
I firstly decided to use NodeJS, but if there is another programming language or Framework more appropriate for this kind of application please let me know.

Comment: Are you planning on supporting interactive commands? How about commands that draw and refresh UIs like `top`?

Comment: yes of course! try the link i gave, you'll see that interactive commands like ping, or top, work! like a charm. that's the main reason i'm asking for advices/ideas because i don't really how to perform that

Comment: This will might be help you ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924485/how-to-create-web-based-terminal-using-xterm-js-to-ssh-into-a-system-on-local-ne?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435856/how-to-access-your-terminal-window-via-the-browser/50942525#50942525

Answer (score 1):

If you want a real terminal in the browser using node.js on the backend, you might give [`tty.js`](https://github.com/chjj/tty.js) a try.

Alternatively you can use the [`pty.js`](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js) module manually which is used by `tty.js`. Along with that, you could also use [`xterm`](https://github.com/sourcelair/xterm.js) for doing the browser-side terminal emulation.

Comment: just warning for others, this hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: FWIW if you want to ssh (indirectly) from the browser, there is [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38690242).