# Connecting to remote SSH server (via Node.js/html5 console)

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, html, ssh

I have been scouring the face of the web looking to answer a question which I had thought would be simple. My goal is straight forward. I want to build out a simple web-based SSH client using Node.js module(s). I have found several options if I want to connect to the node server itself, but can't seem to find any examples of connecting to a REMOTE server.

Essentially the outcome I am looking for is a workflow like this : Connect to webserver -> Click on a server name in a list of servers -> Enter SSH session to the server I clicked on

The only thing I have found that's even remotely close to what I am looking for is [guacamole](https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/). I do not want to use guacamole, however, as I want this application to be OS independent. Currently I am building it on a windows 10 platform, and will port it over to fedora when I am done.

I found this tutorial for [creating an SSH terminal](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/making-simple-web-based-ssh-client-using-nodejs-and-socketio). However, all this does is creates (or attempts to create) an SSH connection to the local system.

Another options that looked absolutely fantastic was [tty.js](https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/). Alas, the bottom-line is the same as the above tutorial. The module only allows you to connect to the node.js server, NOT to remote servers.

Anyone have information on a possible path to this goal?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is easily doable with modules like [`ssh2`](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2), [`xterm`](https://github.com/sourcelair/xterm.js), and [`socket.io`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io).

Here's an example:

1. `npm install ssh2 xterm socket.io`
2. Create `index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SSH Terminal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/xterm.css" />
    <script src="/src/xterm.js"></script>
    <script src="/addons/fit/fit.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var terminalContainer = document.getElementById('terminal-container');
        var term = new Terminal({ cursorBlink: true });
        term.open(terminalContainer);
        term.fit();

        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('connect', function() {
          term.write('\r\n*** Connected to backend***\r\n');

          // Browser -> Backend
          term.on('data', function(data) {
            socket.emit('data', data);
          });

          // Backend -> Browser
          socket.on('data', function(data) {
            term.write(data);
          });

          socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            term.write('\r\n*** Disconnected from backend***\r\n');
          });
        });
      }, false);
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, arial;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #111;
      }
      h1 {
        text-align: center;
      }
      #terminal-container {
        width: 960px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 2px;
      }
      #terminal-container .terminal {
        background-color: #111;
        color: #fafafa;
        padding: 2px;
      }
      #terminal-container .terminal:focus .terminal-cursor {
        background-color: #fafafa;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="terminal-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

3. Create `server.js`:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(onRequest);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var SSHClient = require('ssh2').Client;

// Load static files into memory
var staticFiles = {};
var basePath = path.join(require.resolve('xterm'), '..');
[ 'addons/fit/fit.js',
  'src/xterm.css',
  'src/xterm.js'
].forEach(function(f) {
  staticFiles['/' + f] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, f));
});
staticFiles['/'] = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

// Handle static file serving
function onRequest(req, res) {
  var file;
  if (req.method === 'GET' && (file = staticFiles[req.url])) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/'
                      + (/css$/.test(req.url)
                         ? 'css'
                         : (/js$/.test(req.url) ? 'javascript' : 'html'))
    });
    return res.end(file);
  }
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.end();
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var conn = new SSHClient();
  conn.on('ready', function() {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION ESTABLISHED ***\r\n');
    conn.shell(function(err, stream) {
      if (err)
        return socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH SHELL ERROR: ' + err.message + ' ***\r\n');
      socket.on('data', function(data) {
        stream.write(data);
      });
      stream.on('data', function(d) {
        socket.emit('data', d.toString('binary'));
      }).on('close', function() {
        conn.end();
      });
    });
  }).on('close', function() {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION CLOSED ***\r\n');
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION ERROR: ' + err.message + ' ***\r\n');
  }).connect({
    host: '192.168.100.105',
    username: 'foo',
    password: 'barbaz'
  });
});

server.listen(8000);
```

4. Edit the SSH server configuration passed to `.connect()` in `server.js`
5. `node server.js`
6. Visit http://localhost:8000 in your browser

Comment: Dude, you absolutely rock! :)

Comment: Don't happen to have something similar for RDP & VNC do ya? :)

Comment: A quick search for vnc turns up [this](http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/08/30/vnc-javascript-nodejs/). It's a bit old and could stand to be optimized a bit, but it might still work. As far as RDP goes, I have not seen an RDP implementation/binding for node yet.

Comment: Yep, that's the same thing I found for VNC. I'll mess with that eventually. For RDP, I think this'll work https://github.com/citronneur/node-rdpjs but I'm going to have to find some better documentation than what's on the GIT page.

Comment: @mscdex When I go to http://localhost:8000 it doesn't allow the passing of GET variables (produces white screen).  What modification would need to be made to the answer code above that would allow http://localhost:8000/?foo=bar and then to have access to foo in onRequest(req, res) ?

Comment: @user2058037 You'd have to parse [`req.url`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_message_url) like [`url.parse(req.url, true)`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost). Then use `.pathname` from the resulting object instead of `req.url` for the `staticFiles[]` lookup.

Comment: hi @mscdex, i need to record this terminal.how do i do that?

Comment: @mscdex i found some record solution like asciinema, but user can stop recording. i wanna record terminal in backend in main server (the server nodejs run, not remote one). please help.

Comment: something I am missing. Suppose I have a PC behind a NAT. And I want to access it from Internet. Are these guidelines useful for?

Comment: Great piece of code. I have to warn others that this (and socket.io in general) **will not work** if you happen to use the **express-status-monitor package**. You will get a "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400" and it will drive you crazy. Cheers.

Comment: Can you please specify the versions used here? With the latest versions as of 2020/04/30 and Node 12, this fails with: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/allan.lewis/git/stash-user/yvrc-ssh-term/node_modules/xterm/lib/addons/fit/fit.js'`

Comment: I think the root cause of my issue above is that the `fit` addon has moved into a separate package, `xterm-addon-fit`.

Comment: This is awesome. Note that the xterm API has changed, so instead of term.on('data'... I used term.onData(...

Comment: Is there any way to do the same with python as backend?

Comment: does this code work if i want to connect with my local machine instead of remote machine, i'm getting ECONNREFUSED error.

Comment: Can this solution be used with Java Spring Boot App? I have an Angular + Spring Boot app where I want to connect using SSH, RDP, and Telnet.

Answer (score 6):

Just adding **updated code** to **@mscdex great answer** because the libraries have changed over the years.

Libraries:

```
npm install express socket.io ssh2 xterm xterm-addon-fit
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SSH Terminal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/xterm.css" />
    <script src="/xterm.js"></script>
    <script src="/xterm-addon-fit.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var terminalContainer = document.getElementById('terminal-container');
        const term = new Terminal({ cursorBlink: true });        
        const fitAddon = new FitAddon.FitAddon();
        term.loadAddon(fitAddon);
        term.open(terminalContainer);
        fitAddon.fit();

        var socket = io() //.connect();
        socket.on('connect', function() {
          term.write('\r\n*** Connected to backend ***\r\n');
        });

        // Browser -> Backend
        term.onKey(function (ev) {
          socket.emit('data', ev.key);
        });

        // Backend -> Browser
        socket.on('data', function(data) {
          term.write(data);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
          term.write('\r\n*** Disconnected from backend ***\r\n');
        });
      }, false);
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, arial;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #111;
      }
      h1 {
        text-align: center;
      }
      #terminal-container {
        width: 960px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 2px;
      }
      #terminal-container .terminal {
        background-color: #111;
        color: #fafafa;
        padding: 2px;
      }
      #terminal-container .terminal:focus .terminal-cursor {
        background-color: #fafafa;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>WebSSH</h3>
    <div id="terminal-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(onRequest);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var SSHClient = require('ssh2').Client;

// Load static files into memory
var staticFiles = {};
var basePath = path.join(require.resolve('xterm'), '..');
staticFiles['/xterm.css'] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, '../css/xterm.css'));
staticFiles['/xterm.js'] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, 'xterm.js'));
basePath = path.join(require.resolve('xterm-addon-fit'), '..');
staticFiles['/xterm-addon-fit.js'] = fs.readFileSync(path.join(basePath, 'xterm-addon-fit.js'));
staticFiles['/'] = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

// Handle static file serving
function onRequest(req, res) {
  var file;
  if (req.method === 'GET' && (file = staticFiles[req.url])) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/'
        + (/css$/.test(req.url)
        ? 'css'
        : (/js$/.test(req.url) ? 'javascript' : 'html'))
    });
    return res.end(file);
  }
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.end();
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var conn = new SSHClient();
  conn.on('ready', function() {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION ESTABLISHED ***\r\n');
    conn.shell(function(err, stream) {
      if (err)
        return socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH SHELL ERROR: ' + err.message + ' ***\r\n');
      socket.on('data', function(data) {
        stream.write(data);
      });
      stream.on('data', function(d) {
        socket.emit('data', d.toString('binary'));
      }).on('close', function() {
        conn.end();
      });
    });
  }).on('close', function() {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION CLOSED ***\r\n');
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION ERROR: ' + err.message + ' ***\r\n');
  }).connect({
    host: 'domain.tld',
    port: 22,
    username: 'root',
    privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('path/to/keyfile')
  });
});

let port = 8000;
console.log('Listening on port', port)
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: You should not use the `onKey` event, it is only there for low level event access and rarely needed. Instead use `onData` and `onBinary`, these will nicely wrap everything into bytes meant for the IO sink (incl. mouse reports).

Answer (score 5):

**Same as the above answer but actually using express and modern syntax and libraries**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*"
  }
});
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false,
  limit: '150mb'
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/xterm.css', express.static(require.resolve('xterm/css/xterm.css')));
app.use('/xterm.js', express.static(require.resolve('xterm')));
app.use('/xterm-addon-fit.js', express.static(require.resolve('xterm-addon-fit')));

const SSHClient = require('ssh2').Client;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  res.render('index');
  // I am using ejs as my templating engine but HTML file work just fine.
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var conn = new SSHClient();
  conn.on('ready', function() {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION ESTABLISHED ***\r\n');
    conn.shell(function(err, stream) {
      if (err)
        return socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH SHELL ERROR: ' + err.message + ' ***\r\n');
      socket.on('data', function(data) {
        stream.write(data);
      });
      stream.on('data', function(d) {
        socket.emit('data', d.toString('binary'));
      }).on('close', function() {
        conn.end();
      });
    });
  }).on('close', function() {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION CLOSED ***\r\n');
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    socket.emit('data', '\r\n*** SSH CONNECTION ERROR: ' + err.message + ' ***\r\n');
  }).connect({
    host: '192.168.0.103',
    port: 22,
    username: 'kali',
    password: 'kali'
  });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #111;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#terminal-container {
  width: 960px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px;
}

#terminal-container .terminal {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fafafa;
  padding: 2px;
}

#terminal-container .terminal:focus .terminal-cursor {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SSH SERVER</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/xterm.css" />
  <script defer src="/xterm.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/xterm-addon-fit.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script defer src='/js/app.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/main.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>WebSSH</h3>
  <div id="terminal-container"></div>
  <script>
  // PLEASE USE A SEPERATE FILE FOR THE JS and defer it
  // like the above app.js file 
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      const terminalContainer = document.getElementById('terminal-container');
      const term = new Terminal({
        cursorBlink: true
      });
      const fitAddon = new FitAddon.FitAddon();
      term.loadAddon(fitAddon);
      term.open(terminalContainer);
      fitAddon.fit();

      const socket = io() //.connect();
      socket.on('connect', function() {
        term.write('\r\n*** Connected to backend ***\r\n');
      });

      // Browser -> Backend
      term.onKey(function(ev) {
        socket.emit('data', ev.key);
      });

      // Backend -> Browser
      socket.on('data', function(data) {
        term.write(data);
      });

      socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        term.write('\r\n*** Disconnected from backend ***\r\n');
      });
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how to pass pem here?

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot use `privateKey` instead of `password` in the SSHClient `connect` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Try also noVnc.
However, a little dig within the page of `xterm.js` reveals other solutions, like

[WebSSH2](https://github.com/billchurch/WebSSH2)