# Python SSH Interactive Shell call back on data receive

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko, ssh2

I'm trying to implement a interactive SSH shell using python as back-end. Basically I want to pass each character to shell along with and special character like new line, Ctrl-C. Then pass back the result. I found similar solution in node.js at [Connecting to remote SSH server (via Node.js/html5 console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689707/connecting-to-remote-ssh-server-via-node-js-html5-console)
I can establish a websocket from fronend/JS side and send each character on key-press. But I'm facing problem in getting shell output back. In node.js ssh2 package its looks like on receiving data it can call some function

```
    }).on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
    });
```

I checked the python's `ssh2-python` and `Paramiko`, but in both I see we have to loop continuously and check if any data is available on channel. Do we have something like callback similar to node.js ?
So that I can handle incoming stream + continuous outgoing stream( in case of command like top and ping)