# How to access your terminal window via the browser?

Tags: shell, browser, terminal, server

I want to access my ubuntu terminal using my browser i found a npm package [web-terminal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-terminal) but it is kind off not complete. I have seen jupyter notebook do it. so is there a solution for it or a way to get that terminal thingy out of jupyter notebook.

Example: Just like when u access your google cloud server via your browser with some sort of shell.

[image: Something like this]
[image: Using vim just like a real terminal]

Note: I didn't get anything to start with just the npm web-terminal so i won't be able to show much effort from my side.

Thank you in advance. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i finally found the answer i was looking for.

There is one such tool called [xterm.js](https://xtermjs.org/) and very well applied example of xterm is in jupyter notebook named [termiado](https://github.com/jupyter/terminado).